# No me funciona la perspectiva en CSS

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo el siguiente codigo código, pero por alguna razón no me funciona.

```css
#bienvenida1{  
 width:880px;
 height:320px;
 position:relative;
 top:50px;
 left:40px;
 perspective:150px;
 -webkit-perspective:150px;
}

#bienvenida2{
 background-color:#7596ff;
 position:absolute;
 border:1px solid black;
 -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
     transform: rotateX(20deg); 
}
```

```html
 



<div id="bienvenida1">
    <div id="bienvenida2"></div>
</div>
```

El cuadro no se muestra en el navegador como debería.

Comment: que se supone que debe hacer eso? puedes colocar algun tipo de imagen o ejemplo de donde hallas tomado la idea?

Comment: Debe mostrar un cuadro como el de color rojo idéntico a este http://www.w3big.com/try/try.php?filename=trycss3_perspective1      pero de diferente color

Comment: ya vi, estas probandolo donde, en algun editor online, o en un editor instalado en tu equipo?

Comment: Estoy probando en dos documentos de texto (bloc de notas) uno de css y otro de html, tengo varias formas que tengo que modificar con animaciones, transiciones y transformaciones y con todas pude hacer lo que quería pero esta forma es la única que no me sale.

Comment: Por que no tratas de ir agregando propiedad por propiedad a cada div, a ver cuando dejas de ver los colores y ese tipo de cosas, a ver si es cuando empiezas a jugar con las posiciones

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En `#bienvenida2` olvidaste poner el `padding`. El `padding` es el que te permitirá controlar el tamaño del recuadro que rotas.

Para el ancho que estás manejando un `padding 100px 400px;` te dará el efecto similar al que muestras en el ejemplo:

```
#bienvenida2{
    padding:100px 400px;
    background-color:#7596ff;
    position:absolute;
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    transform: rotateX(20deg);  
}
```

Comment: Justo era eso lo que me faltaba. Gracias :D

Answer (score 0):

Si el `position` del segundo `div` quieres que sea `absolute`, pues podrías probar esto si lo que quieres es, centrarlo como en la imagen:

```
#bienvenida2{
    top:25%;
    left: 25%; 
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#7596ff;
    border:1px solid black;
    -webkit-transform: rotateX(20deg);
    transform: rotateX(20deg);  
}
```

Ponle un fondo o un borde al `div` padre para ver claramente dónde quieres posicionar el segundo.